# Broken project after updating Vuetify

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vuetify.js, upgrade

I've updated Vuetify from version 2.2.x to version 2.4.6 by running `npm uninstall --save vuetify` and then `npm run install --save vuetify@latest`. It's previously installed using `vue add vuetify` Now serving the project spews out these error messages

```
 error  in ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/locale/fi.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user/projects/my-project/node_modules/vuetify/lib/locale/fi.js'

 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/locale/index.js 13:0-37 13:0-37
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/presets/default/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/services/presets/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/services/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/framework.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/plugins/vuetify.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.69:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/locale/sk.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user/projects/my-project/node_modules/vuetify/lib/locale/sk.js'

 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/locale/index.js 30:0-37 30:0-37
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/presets/default/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/services/presets/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/services/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/framework.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/plugins/vuetify.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.69:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/mixins/mobile/index.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user/projects/my-project/node_modules/vuetify/lib/mixins/mobile/index.js'

 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VBanner/VBanner.js 11:0-41 18:30-36
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VBanner/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/plugins/vuetify.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.69:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/mixins/roundable/index.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user/projects/my-project/node_modules/vuetify/lib/mixins/roundable/index.js'

 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VSheet/VSheet.js 9:0-47 15:69-78
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VSheet/index.js
 @ ./src/views/Home.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.69:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/util/dateTimeUtils.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user/projects/my-project/node_modules/vuetify/lib/util/dateTimeUtils.js'

 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VCalendar/VCalendarWeekly.js 16:0-54 122:13-23
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VCalendar/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/plugins/vuetify.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.69:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

 error  in ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/util/dom.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user/projects/my-project/node_modules/vuetify/lib/util/dom.js'

 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VTextField/VTextField.js 25:0-46 416:17-29 464:17-29
 @ ./node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/VTextField/index.js
 @ ./src/views/RestaurantNew/Step1.vue
 @ ./src/router/restaurantManagementRoutes.js
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.69:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

Is there a way to fix this? Looks like I have to somehow purge and reconfigure webpack and/or babel-loader for the new Vuetify version without having to migrate my other project files. I am familiar with neither webpack nor babel.

Comment: You should have a package.lock.json file. Delete that, and also delete the node_modules folder. Re-run npm install and try building again.

Comment: @LordRelix This works. Add this as an answer so I can pick it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a package.lock.json file. Delete that, and also delete the node_modules folder. Re-run npm install and try building again

Comment: For me this started throwing a `Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_exports__.d is undefined  ... stripAnsi.js:18` Error. @Lord Relix